# ¿Cómo pasar una variable de sesión al URL de cualquier página activa?

Tags: php, html

Muy buenas. En mi sistema poseo un menú donde puedo seleccionar varias opciones y según cuál se elija, la información dentro de la página cambia.

Este es un ejemplo de cómo lo tengo:

```html
<ul class="menu">

  <?php 
  $query = find_all('table_name');
  foreach ($query as $que):
  ?>

  <li>
    <a href="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ;?>?campo=<?= que$['id'] ?>">
      <?php echo remove_junk($que['name']) ?>
    </a>
  </li>

  <?php endforeach;?>

</ul>
```

El menú está dentro del navbar princiapal del sitio y posee diferentes enlaces, generados por un `foreach` el cual se carga según los registros encontrados en el query de un función propia llamada `find_all`, que sólo me trae los campos "id" y "name" de cada registro en una tabla de MySQL.

Básicamente, con lo de arriba logro algo así:

```html
<a href= "home.php?campo=1"> Enlace 1 </a>
<a href= "home.php?campo=2"> Enlace 2 </a>
<a href= "home.php?campo=3"> Enlace 3 </a>
<a href= "home.php?campo=4"> Enlace 4 </a>
<a href= "home.php?campo=5"> Enlace 5 </a>
```

Si por ejemplo ya estoy en `home.php`, la página se carga sobre sí misma, pero agregando el valor de campo, que sería el "id" extraído del query. Luego con esto procedo a hacer  una validación para mostrar la información que necesito dentro de la misma página en base a dicho "id":

```html
<?php         
  if (isset($_GET['campo'])){
?> 

  <div> Contenido generado según el id seleccionado </div>

<?php }else { ?>

  <div> Contenido generado si no se establece la variable </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Hasta ahora, esto funciona para cada página, el problema es que debo al entrar en cada página debo volver a seleccionar la opción del menú para que cargue la información que necesito. Por lo que ando buscando generar una variable `$_SESSION` para que guarde la opción seleccionada dentro de cualquier página y se mantenga en el resto hasta que vuelva a ser cambiada o la sesión del usuario se cierre.

Tampoco sé si se puede hacer con otra opción aparte de enlaces. Uso estos para redireccionar automáticamente la página al hacer click con el nuevo URL, pero no sé si se puede hacer con un `button` o algo más.

Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida, gracias.

Comment: Lo que quiere lograr es, que el usuario ingrese/seleccione un `id`, y a partir de ese dato, ponerlo en las diferentes `URL` que se generan en su menú?

Comment: Exactamente. Por ejemplo, pasando del código PHP a HTML puro sería algo así:

<a href=" index.php?campo=1 "> Enlace 1 </a>
<a href=" index.php?campo=2 "> Enlace 2 </a>
<a href=" index.php?campo=3 "> Enlace 3 </a>
<a href=" index.php?campo=4 "> Enlace 4 </a>

Entonces se evaluaría el valor de campo en el URL. Pero quiero que mi selección se mantenga en todas las páginas hasta cerrarse la sesión o hasta que cambie de nuevo el valor presionando otro botón/enlace. Por ahora sólo puedo hacerlo de página en página, sin mantener una variable global o de sesión.

Answer (score 1):

en cada página al principio:

```
<?php
// crea o resume una sesión
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['campo'])) :
    // si campo viene por get crea / reemplaza el valor almacenado en la sesión
    $_SESSION['campo'] = $_GET['campo'];
endif;

// id_seleccionado será igual a campo 
// (sea que vino por get o ya estaba en la sesión) o NULL
$id_seleccionado = (isset($_SESSION['campo']))?$_SESSION['campo']:NULL;

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>usarsesion</title>
</head>
<body>


...
```

Mas adelante en el código podes usar el id

```
<?php 
if  (NULL!=$id_seleccionado) :
?><div> Contenido generado según el id seleccionado </div><?php
    else :
?><div> Contenido generado generado si no se establece la variable</div><?php
endif;
?>
...
</body>
</html>
```

para "desloguear" en un archivo logout.php

```
<?php
// crea o resume una sesión
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>cerrarsesion</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// remueve todas las variables de la sesión
session_unset(); 
// destruye la sesión 
session_destroy(); 
?>
<p>has cerrado la sesión</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede usar un `script` para guardar su `id` en `localStorage` que seria la alternativa a `$_SESSION` pero con `JavaScript`, a mi parecer más sencillo de usar.

Independiente de como obtenga el `ID` lo que debe de hacer para guardarlo en el `session` del navegador es:

```
 //dentro de los corchetes, pone como texto/cadena el nombre de la variable    
 localStorage["ID"] = ID; //guarda como cadena su ID
```

luego de que la tiene almacenada en `localStorage` para llamarla o usarla lo hace así:

```
localStorage.ID;
```

Ahora como ya a creado el menú con las etiquetas `<a>` con sus `href`, lo que hace es obtener el `href` y cambiarlos, agregando el `ID` (en caso de que exista), lo puede hacer así:

```
HTML

<a href= "home.php?campo=1"> Enlace 1 </a>
<a href= "home.php?campo=2"> Enlace 2 </a>
<a href= "home.php?campo=3"> Enlace 3 </a>
<a href= "home.php?campo=4"> Enlace 4 </a>
<a href= "home.php?campo=5"> Enlace 5 </a>
```

`JS`

```
//obtiene todos los elementos <a> 
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
localStorage['id'] = 5; //crea la variable de localStorage

//si existe la varieble localStorage['id']
//cambia las URL agregando el id
if(localStorage.id){
  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
    //obtiene el href actual de todos los elemento a
    var linkTag = tags[i].getAttribute("href");
    //agrega el id al final de la url y cambia el href
    tags[i].href = linkTag + '&id=' + localStorage.id;
  } 
}
```

mire el siguiente link para que observe el trabajo de `localStorage`: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOdbbB